# Why can't the java Iterable interface take a generics wildcard? Or: why can't I an overriding iterator() method return an Iterator for a subclass?

Tags: java, generics, overriding, iterable

I have some classes: SearchResponse, SearchResponseHit, SpecialSearchResponse (extends SearchResponse) and SpecialSearchResponseHit (extends SearchResponseHit).

SearchResponse look something like this:

```
public class SearchResponse implements Iterable<SearchResponseHit> {

    [...]

    public Iterator<SearchResponseHit> iterator() {
        return searchResponseHits.iterator();
    }
}
```

This makes it possible for me to use an instance of SearchResponse in a foreach loop, like this:

```
for (SearchResponseHit hit : mySearchResponse) {
    [...]
}
```

Now, what I want to do, but can't find out how, is to make this code compile when I have an instance of SpecialSearchResponse:

```
for (SpecialSearchResponseHit specialHit : mySpecialSearchResponse) {
    [...]
}
```

This gives me the following compiler error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type SearchResponseHit to SpecialSearchResponseHit
```

If I try to add this code to SpecialSearchResponse:

```
public Iterator<SpecialSearchResponseHit> iterator() {
    [...]
}
```

...I get the error:

```
The return type is incompatible with Iterable<SearchResponseHit>.iterator()
```

I have tried changing the method in SearchResponse to:

```
    public Iterator<? extends SearchResponseHit> iterator() {
        return searchResponseHits.iterator();
    }
```

...but this gives me the error:

```
The return type is incompatible with Iterable<SearchResponseHit>.iterator()
```

Then I tried changing the class definition to:

```
public class SearchResponse implements Iterable<? extends SearchResponseHit>
```

...but this gives me this error:

```
    The type SearchResponse cannot extend or implement Iterable<? extends SearchResponseHit>. A supertype may not specify any wildcard
```

What is the best (and prettiest) way to solve this? Or do I have to skip the foreach-method (and other functions that use the Iterable interface behind the scenes) and write a getSpecialIterator() method and then use the iterator directly?

Regards
/J

Comment: I think this is a generics issue rather than Iterable. Besides, you haven't shown `SearchResponse` extends `SearchResponseHit`.

Comment: Well, regardless of how to categorize this issue ("generics" or "Iterable"), the problem is real and palpable. Also, SearchResponse doesn't and shouldn't extend SearchResponseHit, so where did you get that from?

Comment: Mybad, I meant `SpecialSearchResponse` but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to declare the various classes in the following way:

```
public class SearchResponse<T  extends SearchResponseHit> implements Iterable<T> {
    List<T> searchResponseHits;

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return searchResponseHits.iterator();
    }
}

public class SearchResponseHit {}

public class SpecialSearchResponse extends SearchResponse<SpecialSearchResponseHit> {}
public class SpecialSearchResponseHit extends SearchResponseHit {}
```

That way you can call them like this:

```
    SearchResponse<SearchResponseHit> sr = new SearchResponse<SearchResponseHit>();
    for (SearchResponseHit h : sr) {}

    SpecialSearchResponse ssr = new SpecialSearchResponse();
    for (SpecialSearchResponseHit h : ssr) {}
```

But that introduces generics in the `SearchResponse` class and you can't simply declare `SearchResponse sr = new SearchResponse()` any longer (without warnings & casts).

---

**UPDATE**
Following your comment, you could alternatively create a common superclass that contains the generics boilerplate - you could make it abstract and package private so the user of your classes does not see it:

```
abstract class AbstractSearchResponse<T  extends SearchResponseHit> implements Iterable<T>{
    List<T> searchResponseHits;

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return searchResponseHits.iterator();
    }
}

public class SearchResponse extends AbstractSearchResponse<SearchResponseHit> { }
public class SpecialSearchResponse extends AbstractSearchResponse<SpecialSearchResponseHit> {}
```

Now you can call the 2 children as you wanted:

```
SearchResponse sr = new SearchResponse();
for (SearchResponseHit h : sr) {}

SpecialSearchResponse ssr = new SpecialSearchResponse();
for (SpecialSearchResponseHit h : ssr) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, assylias. But I have to say that adding this extra code just to make the compiler happy, but the coder unhappy, is not good enough for me. I can't really understand why Java is working against me in this case. What is the logical reasoning behind this limitation?

Comment: Thanks for the updated suggestion, I marked your suggestion as the accepted answer (don't have enough reputation to do an up vote, though). However I'll think actually prefer keeping the simple class structure I have now, where SpecialSearchResponse actually extends SearchResponse (having an abstract ancestor whould be fine, if I never would have to reference it from the outside, but there are cases when I would have needed too). So I guess I would just have to accept the fact that Java is limited in this way.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has good work-arounds, but as to why this is a problem in the first place, it's because Iterable is poorly defined.  The signature of the iterator method should be `Iterator<? extends T> iterator()`.  Since all of `Iterator<T>`'s methods only use the type parameter T in a covariant way, `Iterator<T>` is equivalent to `Iterator<? extends T>`, but the wildcard version is more flexible.  The only argument against doing this is if you think you will add contravariant usages of T in the future (like `insert(T obj)` for example).  However, doing this would probably warrant a new interface anyway.